# Trying to push an image to the docker registry

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to push a docker image to the docker hub (registry) but I am getting an error. What would be the problem here?

```
   root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~# docker login
Login with your Docker ID to push and pull images from Docker Hub. If you `don't have a Docker ID, head over to https://hub.docker.com to create one.`
Username : 
Password: 
Login Succeeded
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~# docker push nodevolume/new:0.1
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/nodevolume/new]
c5bcc1df7ac9: Preparing 
6f6073c5df6d: Preparing 
dec9270df6f5: Preparing 
9f7fef8e5d59: Preparing 
346f6530205e: Preparing 
98a7412556fb: Waiting 
7598955b0d14: Waiting 
5f70bf18a086: Waiting 
5b5be35aaec4: Waiting 
4e2fee1e7083: Waiting 
1822b2b47122: Waiting 
7394707b3914: Waiting 
unauthorized: authentication required
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~#
```

IN my logs it shows:

```
    time="2016-05-11T12:45:31.133777251-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T12:45:31.136657146-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T12:45:31.138376928-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T12:45:31.140385526-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T12:45:31.141045576-04:00" level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T13:11:48.838177306-04:00" level=error msg="Upload failed: unauthorized: authentication required" 
time="2016-05-11T13:11:48.839113848-04:00" level=error msg="Attempting next endpoint for push after error: unauthorized: authentication required" 
root@ubuntu-512mb-nyc2-01:~#
```

NODE VERSION - This is the version of node I am using. How do I tell if I have the right permissions to push to Docker Hub?

```
    Client:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   5604cbe
 Built:        Tue Apr 26 23:30:23 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: What version of docker are you using? (`docker version`) Does your account have permissions to push to the "nodevolume/new" repository on Docker Hub? (The nodevolume user seems to give a 404 to me https://hub.docker.com/u/nodevolume/)

Comment: I posted my docker server and client version above. Also, i think it gives a 404 because I couldnt push to hub yet. Do I need to create a repository in the docker hub first?

Comment: If your username on hub is "nodevolume", it should be visible, even if you don't have a repository pushed yet

Comment: Do you mean it should be created on the dockerhub website first before its manually pushed?

Comment: Ok, thanks much ! That was right. I wasn't using my name to push the upload to. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I wrote it down as an answer below, so that you can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to push to an account that you don't have access to; the `nodevolume/new` repository is referring to the `nodevolume` account on Docker Hub (but that account doesn't exist). Change this to `<your-hub-account>/new` and you should be able to push the image.

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help